# The method run(Class<MyNewAppApplication>, String[]) is undefined for the type String

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I imported my project that was working normally before and after I changed my OS [ same OS ] when I imported this project as existing maven project in STS , it says `The method run(Class<MyNewAppApplication>, String[]) is undefined for the type String` and shows nothing else. 
Other file is working and it show this error and I literally have no idea of what is happening.

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class MyNewAppApplication {

    private static final String SpringApplication = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(MyNewAppApplication.class, args);   

    }
}
```

it shows error at `run()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a static field SpringApplication

```
 private static final String SpringApplication = null;
```

Remove that line because this hides the SpringApplication class

Comment: It works now. But I did not do anything I just Imported  why it was working previously ? I think I didn't add this line ?

Comment: I'm sure you have. This line is not comming from Spring Boot starter.